# Problems with SQLite and VS2013

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've got a (hopefully) simple question. We're using Visual Studio 2013 and have a .Net 4.0 project. We would like to use a SQLite Database in this project. But all we can find are installations for VS2010 + .Net 4.0. If i Install this Version I cannot add a SQLite Connection in the Server Explorer view.

Is this in generall not possible or is there a way to add a SQLite Connection using VS2013 and .Net 4.0?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add the SQLite-dll to References, and add a `using SQLite` to include the SQLite.cs file you also need.


This will perhaps help you:
[CodeProject -> Using SQLite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the [SQLite package](https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.97.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.97.0.exe) for .NET 4.5.1 with design-time components for Visual Studio 2013.

Unfortunately, as stated on the SQLite website:

> This setup package features the mixed-mode assembly and will install
>   all the necessary runtime components and dependencies for the x86
>   version of the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.97.0 (3.8.10.2) package. The
>   Visual C++ 2013 Update 2 runtime for x86 is included. The .NET
>   Framework 4.5.1 is required.
>   **This is the only setup package that is
>   capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio
>   2013.**

So you would have to choose between:

- Upgrade your project to .NET Framework 4.5.1
- Use the SQLite dll for .NET Framework 4.0 and don't have the design-time components